# Can the inequality $\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b} \geq 6$ be proved with differentiation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, inequality, fractions, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

$$\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b} \geq 6,\quad \text{with}\quad a,b,c >  0$$

I could do it with letting $x=\frac{a}{b}$, $y=\frac{b}{c}$, $z=\frac{c}{a}$, but I wonder if it is solvable somehow with differentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider you that you look for the minimum of function $$\Phi=\frac{a+b}{c} + \frac{b+c}{a} + \frac{c+a}{b} \tag 1$$ Compute the partial derivatives 
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{da}=-\frac{b+c}{a^2}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\tag 2$$
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{db}=-\frac{a+c}{b^2}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}\tag 3$$
$$\frac{\partial\Phi}{dc}=-\frac{a+b}{c^2}+\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\tag 4$$ and say that all of them are equal to $0$.

From $(2)$ solve the quadratic for $b$. The two roots are
$$b_1=\frac {a^2} c\qquad \text{and}\qquad b_2=-c\implies b=\frac {a^2} c$$ since $a,b,c$ are positive.

Plug $b=\frac {a^2} c$ in $(3)$ to get $$\frac{(a+c) \left(a^3-c^3\right)}{a^4 c}=0\implies c=a\implies b=c=a$$
Plug in $(4)$ to get $0=0$.

Replace in $(1)$ and get $6$.

Comment: Besides one has to verify that the minimum does exist here, often a nontrivial task in general.

Comment: @A.Γ. I totally agree (for sure).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for! Plugging in another numbers, and getting a number greater than 6 is enough to prove if it's really a minima?

Comment: @Botond. I never used $6$ before the conclusion. Cheers.

Comment: But how could I prove if that is really a minima, and not a maxima or just an inflection point?

Comment: @Botond. You are totally correct. What needs to be looked at is the Hessian matrix.

Comment: I haven't heard about it, but I will try to look after it. Thanks!

Comment: @Botond You may multiply by $abc$ to get equivalent $$ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)-6abc\ge 0.$$ The LHS is a homogeneous polynomial, hence it is enough to minimize it over e.g. $a+b+c=1$. With the new constraint the set is compact, i.e. minimum exist. Then apply a similar necessary condition.

Comment: @A.Γ. what do you mean exactly?

Comment: @Botond I mean that minimum of $f(x)$ subject to $g(x)=0$ is at those points where the gradients of $f$ and $g$ are parallel. It gives you similar condition as in this answer, but the minimum exists for sure. Again, this will be much longer calculations than by using AM-GM or similar proofs which are basically "one line proof".

Comment: @A.Γ. I'm getting totally confused. I have tried the partial differentiation on your equation, summed the 3, and I've got a=b=c. But this seems incomplete for me, It feels like I could miss out some root.

Comment: @Botond If you sum up the three equations you will get something like $(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0$, and $a=b=c$ is the only solution. However, as the set $a>0$, $b>0$, $c>0$ is not bonded, you still need to work out existence of the minimum. It is not very hard though from homogeneity of the objective function.

Comment: @A.Γ. Could you please show me the proper way of doing it?

Comment: @Botond One way is to minimize the LHS over $a+b+c=1$ using [KKT theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions). Another way is to notice that the LHS is $$a(b-c)^2+b(a-c)^2+c(a-b)^2$$ which has the minimum at $a=b=c$.

Comment: Thanks! Even though it can be easier to calculate the number, it's hard to prove it completely this way. Or at least I need to learn more about this topic.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it by differentiation too. In your terms, the LHS becomes
$$
x+\frac{1}{x}+y+\frac{1}{y}+z+\frac{1}{z}.
$$
By differentiation, you can show that 
$$
t+\frac{1}{t}\ge 2,\quad t>0.
$$
It gives the result.

Comment: Thanks, this is the way I would do it. But I am looking for a solution (if there is any) which involves more differentiation, because it's not easy to find the ideal transformation every time.

Comment: @Botond Do you mean by "more differentiation" that you optimize the left hand side w.r.t. three variables and show that it is $\ge 6$? Theoretically it is possible, but I would not recommend that. I think this kind of exercises is exactly about to find a transformation (avoiding the standard approach) that makes the proof easy - see the other answers, for example.

Comment: Yes. I know, but sometimes it's easier to do it that way. And the more you know, the better it is.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by differentiation but it is much easier to use $x^2 \geq 0$.

Assuming $a,b,c $ are positive
\begin{eqnarray*}
a(b-c)^2+b(c-a)^2+c(a-b)^2 \geq 0 \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Expand these out
\begin{eqnarray*}
ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a) \geq 6abc \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Now divide by $abc$.

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

By AM-GM for positive variables:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a}\geq2\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{a}\geq6\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{bc}}{a}}=6.$$

AM-GM it's the Jensen inequality for $f(x)=\ln{x}$ because $f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0$.

Comment: What does the cyc mean?

Comment: @Botond This is the standard notation meaning that the variables $(a,b,c)$ are subject to all possible cyclic permutations, one for each summation term.

Comment: @Botond Sorry. I did not see your question.  For example, $\sum\limits_{cyc}a=a+b+c$, $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{a}=\frac{b+c}{a}+\frac{c+a}{b}+\frac{a+b}{c}$

Answer (score -2):

This is a standard example: it's equivalent to
$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\right)\ge9$$
which is AM/HM or Cauchy-Schwarz (provided all $a$, $b$, $c$ are non-negative).

Comment: Does not answer the question.

Comment: $a,b,c$ must be positive, not non-negative. $a$ or $b$ or $c$ can't be zero because $\frac{a}{b}$ or something else would be undefined.